# How to create this animation in spritekit without texture atlas

Tags: swift, animation, sprite-kit, game-physics, texture-atlas

I am trying to create an vine animation in spritekit that looks like this

[image]

I'm trying to recreate an effect similar to this game called prune.

[**this gif shows**](https://media.giphy.com/media/1hAW3PaoPQgoIEzc0B/giphy.gif) what the game looks like

I havent been able to find a library that does might help me animate my graphics like this.

I have found just one technique for animation and that is by using texture atlases.

I can create a texture atlas for an animation like this because then I will have to create lots of images for different kinds of vines that I plan to use and

Is this a way except texture atlases to animate my vine like this ?

Note that I all I have with me right now is a complete illustration of my vine in illustrator.

Comment: unless you manage to find a vine animation library, you are probably going to have to make texture atlases. the other way is to programmatically draw it which would likely be even more difficult.

Comment: what exactly do you want me to look for.

Comment: @AmanKapoor Sorry ? what do you mean

Comment: I dont want you to look for anything? I'm saying unless you find someone that has done this already you will need to do it.

Comment: This is something SKShapeNode is great for.  Figure out the path for each "frame" of your animation, and constantly update the path on the shape node with the desired path you want to display each new frame